# Oracle Peoplesoft and SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, peoplesoft

I recently interviewed for a job where the panel indicated one of their data sources is Oracle PeopleSoft.

I have experience performing analysis and developing directly in Oracle Database using SQL Developer. Can someone please indicate exactly what PeopleSoft is and if I would be able to use SQL Developer to query/develop in this product?

Comment: It's a business application that runs on top of the database. One of the modules is hiEd, so all about an it system for universities are

Comment: I see--thanks for clarifying Jeff. So it sounds like it would simply be an issue of requesting (privileged) schema creation within the same instance. I'd develop an analytical reporting environment for that department in the new schema. The download/setup for SQL developer is pretty effortless!

Comment: yeah, you'd just ask for a user on the peoplesoft system, then you'd pull data per usual - you'll just have learn their data model

Answer (score 1):

PeopleSoft is an ERP with modules related to Finance, Human Resources etc. The web pages in PeopleSoft are developed using its own PeopleCode language. SQL scripts are run in SQL Developer application based on the module environment.

Answer (score 0):

Think of PeopleSoft as a web application to manage an Enterprise's various functions or business processes like Human Resources (Hire to Fire or Retire), Finance & Supply Chain Management (Order to Cash or Procure to Pay), Enterprise Learning Management.

End Users login into an internet/Intranet portal (html) developed using Peoplesoft proprietary language called PeopleCode.

PeopleSoft standard Internet Architecture looks like this:
End User  <-> Web server (Oracle Weblogic / IB Webspehere / Microsoft IIS)  <-> Application Server (Bea Tuxedo) <-> DB (Could be Oracle , Microsoft, DB2 etc)

SQL is used while making DB calls within Peoplecode. Or when writing SQR program for reporting or processing.

Answer (score 0):

most of the implementation of peoplesoft use oracle dbms although not mandatory, Peoplesoft allow to directly use some of dbms statement e.g in peoplecode using SQLexec